# The conditional pdf of 3 iid random variables from an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider three iid random varaiables from an exponential distribution, $X_1,X_2,X_3 \sim$ Exponential$(1)$, each with a pdf $f(x) = e^{-x}  , \space \text{where } x >0$. Determine the conditional pdf of the maximum of the sample given using the minimum of the sample, i.e. $f_{X_{(3)}|X_{(1)}} (y \space|\space x)$.

> **My process**
>
> For a continuous random variable the conditional pdf of a probability function of $X$ given $Y$ is $$f_{X|Y}(x,y) = \dfrac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
> From what I can find online, to find the conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X$ we have to find $f_X(x)$, the marginal pdf of $X$ first, which I can do by integrating the joint pdf $f(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. How do I find the joint pdf of these three variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the joint pdf of the three *independent* samples is the product of their marginal pdf, which you already know.   That is $f_X(z)=e^{-z}\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant 0}$, and also $F_X(z)=(1-e^{-z})\,\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant 0}$ is the CDF of the random variable.   So $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(u,v,w) = f_X(u)\,f_X(v)\,f_X(w)$

*However*, no ; you don't just integrate the joint pdf of the samples; that will find you the marginal of the *first sample*, not the *least sample*.   You want to find the **First Order Statistic**'s pdf.

The favoured outcomes of this (zero measure) event are those consisting of: a selection of one from three samples to be at the value, with the other two samples greater than it.   Hence the probability density function of the first order statistic is:

$$f_{X_{(1)}}(x) = 3\, f_X(x)\,(1-F_X(x))^2$$

By similar reasoning the joint pdf of the minimum and maximum sample values is the density measure of the event where : we select two samples with these two values while the third lies somewhere between them.:

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(3)}}(x,y) = 3!\, f_X(x)\,f_{X}(y)\,(F_X(y)-F_X(x))$$

Hence $$f_{X_{(3)}\mid X_{(1)}}(y\mid x) ~=~\dfrac{2 f_X(y)\,(F_X(y)-F_X(x))}{(1-F_X(x))^2}$$

Substitute and simplify.

Comment: In this case, what would $f_X(y)$ and $F_X(y)$ actually be? Silly question I know, but because of the three variables...

Comment: $f_X(y)~=~e^{-y}\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant 0}$ and $F_X(y)~=~(1-e^{-y})\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant 0}$.  Just a change of tokens.  (iid:= independent and identically distributed) $f_X(y)$ is the probability density function for an arbitrary one of the three variables measured at $y$. @GBTV